# How to synchronize UITableView scrolling and CoraData fetch on iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I want to implement the following function, can you any help me out.

I have core data base in my app. In that data base one model `CourseEvents` contain more then 150000 records, and each record having around 12 fields.

Each records value for one `UITableViewCell`.

But i don't want to fetch all the records in a single fetch request. want to fetch the some `N` number of records according to the `UITableView` scroll.

Example:

When table view load first time want to fetch 200 records, whenever user scroll the `UITableView` need to fetch next 200 record, like need to fetch the data from model based on the scrolling of the `UITableview`.

How can i achieve this. kindly help.....

Comment: what have you tried so far? Have you looked into fetchLimits and fetchOffset of `NSFetchRequest` already?

Comment: i know fetchlimit. but i didnot look for fetchoffset. but i concern is when loading tableview it should fetch first 200(for example), when user scroll up and it reach 150 cell then need to fetch next 200 (201-400), if user again scroll down, need to fetch previous 200 (1 - 200). like my fetch should synchronize with `UITableView` visible cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, When you load the view initially you only want to fetch 200 records and on tableView Scroll you want to fetch next 200 and so on. You are using core data then it's easier to fetch records with the help of [NSFetchedResultsController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController%5fClass/Reference/Reference.html). Just set the `setFetchBatchSize` to whatever records you want to fetch (20 should be good in your case also). There are so many examples available online and great apple samples also available. Here is the link of [CoreDataBooks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/CoreDataBooks/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple%5fref/doc/uid/DTS40008405) example. This is great [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller) on how to use NSFetchedResultsController. And Finally [Core Data Programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdBasics.html#//apple%5fref/doc/uid/TP40001650-TP1) is there for your help. here is the sample code on how to use NSFetchedResultController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSError *error;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
        // Update to handle the error appropriately.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        exit(-1);  // Fail
    }


}

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
        entityForName:@"FailedBankInfo" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
        initWithKey:@"details.closeDate" ascending:NO];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
        [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
            managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil
            cacheName:@"Root"];
    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    id  sectionInfo =
        [[_fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    EntityName *entity = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = entity.name; //just example
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",
        entity.city, entity.state];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell =
        [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Set up the cell...
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: can you explain, in ur code where then next 200 records are getting fetch from database while my tableview scroll.

Comment: NSFetchedResultsController will handle fetching subset(ex 20 items from core data store) of data and it will fetch more when you scroll the tableview. You don't need to put any code to handle fetching of data, it will be handled internally by NSFetchedResultsCntroller. Try the sample code or tutorial link.

Comment: yes, my mistake was. i had separate model class, so from my view i thought i should call when ever scroll happen in `UITableView` but now i got it how to achieve with this code. Thanks lot @suhit.

Comment: @Nagarajan Will you Please share your code, Where you have been added code to fetch next 200 records and how? I have the same issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DaxeshNagar just read suhit sample code and explanation in comments, u can get it.

Answer (score 2):

This sample project helped me a lot to implement my solution. It may help you too. https://github.com/lukagabric/LargeDatasetSample